# Magento1 How to extract image from content?

Tags: magento-1.9, image, static-block

I have static block with below content.

```
<p><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/test.html"><img title="test" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test.jpg"}}" alt="test" /></a></p>
<p>lorem ipsum.</p>
```

What i have tried so far?

```
$html = '<p><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/test.html"><img title="test" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test.jpg"}}" alt="test" /></a></p>
<p>lorem ipsum.</p>';


$dom = new domDocument;
    $dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $imgs  = $dom->getElementsByTagName("img");
    $links = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < $imgs->length; $i++) {
       echo $links = $imgs->item($i)->getAttribute("src");
    }
```

its give me result :

```
{{media url=
```

Comment: I think it create an issue because of double quote , If you remove double quote from media url then it seems fine for you, like {{media url=wysiwyg/test.jpg}}

Comment: @KeyurShah Yes. But it will be dynamic admin user will add imges using. wysiwyg editor so i need to make it dynamic.

Comment: I am not sure but I think regex will help you. just add $html = preg_replace('/((\S)+\s*(=)\s*)(\")(\S+(?<!=.))(\")/', '$1$5', $html);
 after your $html , this regex will remove all double quote from your html. and this will be trick for you. And if you have more dynamic content with the quote then you can replace only double quote with the src attribute.

Comment: @KeyurShah Great I am geting url like this `{{media url=wysiwyg/test.jpg` so i can remove `{{media url=` and use this for now as temporary hack.

Comment: glad to hear that somehow it helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comment It create an issue because double quote `(" ")`, so I think `regex` will be your friend.

```
 $html = '<p><a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/test.html"><img title="test" src="{{media url="wysiwyg/test.jpg"}}" alt="test" /></a></p>
<p>lorem ipsum.</p>';
```

After this line, write below regex

```
$html = preg_replace('/((\S)+\s*(=)\s*)(\")(\S+(?<!=.))(\")/', '$1$5', $html);
```

This regex will remove `double quote` from your `html`. And If you have more dynamic `html` then you can create a new `regex` to remove double quote only from `src` attribute.